# What is the difference between FormSection and Fields

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

What is the difference between redux-form's FormSection and Fields component. When to use which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Fields`

It's similar to `Field`, but you work with multiple fields at once.
It's useful if you want to have access to the state of one of `A` when interacting with `B`; for example:

```
const CitySelection = ({ state, city }) => (
  <div>
    {/* Whenever the state is changed, the city value is reset */}
    <select { ...state.input } onChange={event => {
      state.input.onChange( event );
      city.input.onChange( null );
    }}>
      <option>Choose your state</option>
    </select>
    <select { ...city.input }></select>
  </div>
);

<Fields names={[ "state", "city" ]} component={ CitySelection } />
```

**Please note that, as of v6.5.0, it's rather limited.**
`Field` allows you to pass event handlers (`onChange`, `onBlur`, etc), inline validators, etc. `Fields` don't.

**Please note also that `Fields` may cause performance issues**. This is because the whole component re-renders together.

<sub>Honestly, I never needed to use `Fields` after 6 months using Redux Form. If you find a legitimate reason, let me know so I can improve this answer!</sub>

---

### `FormSection`

It allows you to split parts of your form into smaller components, *in a high level way*.
Unlike `Fields`, you won't be dealing with low level `input` and `meta` props. Therefore, if you want to know about the state of other fields within the same section, you'll need to connect it to the Redux store.

Another difference is that fields within a `FormSection` inherit the section name as the field names prefix.

```
const Address = () => (
  <div>
    <Field name="state" component="select" />
    <Field name="city" component="select" />
  </div>
);

<FormSection name="homeAddress" component={ Address } />
<FormSection name="workAddress" component={ Address } />
```

In this case, your form will have values `homeAddress.city`, `homeAddress.state`, `workAddress.city` and `workAddress.state`.

Answer (score 1):

The FormSection component split forms into smaller components, think like a section in HTML.

Field basically is the minimum element within a form (any input), you can customize any field by passing the out of the box components or use any custom.

Each Field will be connected to the redux store via form-reducer.

In a very basic form, you just need to use the Fields and FormSections are not mandatory at all, take a look at the [simplest](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/simple/) example in redux-forms documentation.